# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am building demo of camera(including, taking picture, save in gallery), but I am getting error of **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**.
I tried to solve in different ways but I could not. If you have any solution so,  let me know.

Error is occuring because of below code

```
List<CameraDescription> camera = [];
```

.

```
    class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen>
        with WidgetsBindingObserver{
    _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
     @override
          void initState() {
            onNewCameraSelected(camera[0]);
            super.initState();
          }

     @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return Scaffold(
              _ _ _ 
              );
          }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not getting any data on `camera`. You can skip the error like,

```dart
 if(tasks.isNotEmpty)onNewCameraSelected(camera[0]);
```

And for N number

```dart
 if(tasks.length>=n-1)onNewCameraSelected(camera[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty:  0**
is generated whenever you try to call an empty or null list
possible there is no data filed in your List